# adding rows to a tibble based on mostly replicating existing rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that only shows a variable if it is not 0. However, I would like to have gaps representing these 0s in the graph.

(I will be working from a large dataframe, but have created an example data based on how I will be manipulating it for this purpose.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

A <- tibble(
    name = c("CTX_M", "CblA_1"),
    rpkm = c(350, 4),
    sample = "A"
)

B <- tibble(
    name = c("CTX_M", "OXA_1", "ampC"),
    rpkm = c(324, 357, 99), 
    sample = "B"
)

plot <- bind_rows(A, B)

ggplot()+ geom_col(data = plot, aes(x = sample, y = rpkm, fill = name), 
    position = "dodge")
```

Sample A and B both have CTX_M, however the othre three "names" are only present in either sample A or sample B. When I run the code, the output graph shows two bars for sample A and three bars for sample B the resulting graph was:

[image: resulting graph]

Is there a way for me to add ClbA_1 to sample B with rpkm=0, and OXA_1 and ampC to sample A with rpkm=0, while maintaining sample separation? - so the tibble would look like this (order not important):

[image: tibble would look like this]

and the graph would therefore look like this:

[image: graph would therefore look like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `complete` from `tidyr`.

```r
plot <- plot %>% complete(name,sample,fill=list(rpkm=0))

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  name   sample  rpkm
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
1 ampC   A          0
2 ampC   B         99
3 CblA_1 A          4
4 CblA_1 B          0
5 CTX_M  A        350
6 CTX_M  B        324
7 OXA_1  A          0
8 OXA_1  B        357

ggplot()+ geom_col(data = plot, aes(x = sample, y = rpkm, fill = name), 
                   position = "dodge")
```

[image]